# Apache serve content of subdirectories as if it were in root directory

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have projects on my webserver organized in folders by category:

```
/var/www/html/
├── categoryA
│   ├── project1
│   └── project2
├── categoryB
│   └── project3
└── categoryC
    ├── project4
    ├── project5
    └── project6
```

I'd like to configure apache to serve everything in category folders as if it was in html folder. So address `example.com/categoryB/project3` would be equivalent to `example.com/project3`.

I already tried to use Alias in apache configuration file and it worked but I have to write a new alias for every new project. I would prefer a solution that works for every new project and every new category folder automaticly.

If possible I'd like to do it using a .htaccess file.

Answer (score 0):

First bear in mind that httpd.conf is a configuration file, not a scripting environment. That said, if you keep a strict naming convention for your directories, you might be able to do something similar. Let say that each "project" name include a clue about its category, you might be able to do something like :

```
URL: http://your.server/Aproject1
Dest : http://your.server/CategoryA/project1

RewriteRule ^/(.)(.*) /Category$1/$2
```

Would have to be tested though